# Prevent org-mode from unfolding pasted outlines

Tags: org-mode, outline

When I copy an outline into an `org-mode` buffer, Emacs automatically unfolds it.  How can I prevent it from doing so?

I always want the outlines I paste in to be fully folded.

Here's an example:

If my org-mode buffer looks like:

```
* A
** AA
*** AAA
** AB
*** ABA
* B
** BA
*** BAA
** BB
*** BBA
* C
** CA
*** CAA
** CB
*** CBA
```

and I fold all those outlines up, so that org shows them as:

```
* A...
* B...
* C...
```

Then I cut (or kill) the `* A...` outline, so I'm just left with:

```
* B...
* C...
```

Normally, by default, when I paste (or yank) the previously cut (killed) `* A...` outline, org inserts it and unfolds it so that it looks like:

```
* B...
* A
** AA
*** AAA
** AB
*** ABA
* C...
```

Instead, when I paste it in, I'd like it to be fully folded, so that it looks like:

```
* B...
* A...
* C...
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "fully folded"?  If you paste an org outline with a single root heading do you only want to see that heading?  Do you want to see all subheadings?  Do you want to see folded property drawers or just the headings?

Comment: There is a configuration value `org-yank-folded-subtrees` that may accomplish what you desire, but seems to require that you use `org-cut-special` (`C-c C-x C-w`) to kill the subtree and yank with `org-paste-special` (`C-c C-x C-y`).

Comment: ebpa: I just provided an example of what I mean above.  `org-cut-special` and `org-paste-special` do indeed do what I need.  I just have to make sure to use those when I'm cutting and pasting in outlines.

Comment: @ebpa it looks like izkon found you comment useful! Please post your answer!

Comment: @Melioratus done :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a configuration value `org-yank-folded-subtrees` that accomplishes this, but you need to use:

1. `org-cut-special` (<kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-w</kbd>) to kill the subtree initially and then
2. `org-paste-special` (<kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-y</kbd>) to yank that subtree